# Is a feasible solution with exactly $m$ positive components, Necessarily an extreme point?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Assume this problem is given:

$Max \space\space z=C^T X$
$s.t. \space\space AX=B$
$X \ge 0$

Such that $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix which has linearly independent rows and $m \lt n$.

Question:

> Assume that $\hat X$ is a feasible solution with exactly $m$ positive
>   components. Is $\hat X$ necessarily an extreme point?

Note 1:  This question is taken from [Bazaraa's Book](https://books.google.com/books?id=AW9v7GyuncsC&pg=PT150&lpg=PT150&dq=exactly%20m%20positive%20components.%20Is%20x%C2%AF%20necessarily%20an%20extreme%20point%20of%20X%20%3D%20%7BAx%20%3D%20b,%20x%20%E2%89%A5%200%7D?&source=bl&ots=zUpckEFFUA&sig=Ec6KcUuA6fv__cCzdojB7EmJVHs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLoIW38PbSAhXMkiwKHZ9SCZQQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=is%20it%20neccessarily&f=false) (3.13, Part d).

Note 2:  I think that we can say this solution is non-degenerate. (Is it true?) But, Is this enough to show that $\hat X$ corresponds to an extreme point?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to Bertsimas, it isn't guaranteed to be an extreme point if there are degenerate vertices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x$ is an extreme point $\Longleftrightarrow$ $x$ is a basic feasible solution $\Longleftrightarrow$
the positive components of $x$ correspond to linearly independent columns of $A$.